# Problems commiting deleted directory to SVN repository

Tags: svn

I am trying to remove a directory from my repository. I delete the folder and do an svn commit and i get the following error :

> Error: Commit failed (details follow):
>
> Error: Access denied

My user has rw permissions on [/], and i can commit new or modified files

any ideas on what the problem might be?

EDIT:

Seems i can perform single file deletes but i cannot remove a directory. Example
i can remove
\data\a.txt
but not 
\data

EDIT2:
my authz

> [aliases]
>    * =
>
> [groups]
>
> # harry_and_sally = harry,sally
>
> # harry_sally_and_joe = harry,sally,&joe
>
> [/]
>
> beta = rw
>
> peras= rw

my password

> [users]
>
> beta = Bunny1981
>
> peras = MyDearBunny

**EDIT:**
solution is on comments of the right answer

Comment: Can you commit new files or edit old files in the repository?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using path-based authorization?  If so, check your authz configuration for errors.

If you had said you could checkout, but not commit (add/modify/delete) and verified that authorization is OK, then I'd say check your working copy URL server name, there is a tricky issue (with path-based authorization) where checkout is case-insensitive (for server name), but commit is case-sensitive. In that case you need to do a relocate.

EDIT:  Can you perform the delete remotely?

`svn delete URL`

That would remove the WC as source of problem.

Comment: I still get a access denied when i perform the svn delete

Comment: Using svn delete URL i.e. remotely?  If so, then I think it has to be authz issue, post your authz file and (edited) passwd file.

Comment: Only things I can think of are either you're entering wrong credentials when removing the folder (are you using the same username), or the [aliases] * = line (why is that there?) is causing problems. Also, ensure a blank line is at the end of both files, I've ran into problems with this in the past.

Comment: You were right, that aliases line was messing up with the server, after i removed it things work as expected thx for all the help

Comment: You're welcome. Funny how the answer gets 0 upvotes and the answer with most votes is not even close ;-)

Answer (score 6):

When you delete the folder from the file system SVN believes something's missing in your copy, so it shows an error.

Instead, you should not delete the folder manually but telling SVN to delete it - that way SVN will delete the folder contents and mark it for deletion upon next commit.

You can use "svn rm" command for that operation.

Comment: The error being reported is an authorization error. An svn st would report missing directory, but a commit should not report it as "access denied".

Comment: I use Tortoise SVN and I used to delete folders the way you said till I realized that folder isn't a windows folder as is but an SVN folder and all (or almost) things have to be done with SVN.

Comment: your answer actually has nothing to do with my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Tell SVN that you want to delete the folder with "svn rm", then commit.